# Exclude files with maven assembly does not work

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have very simple assembly descriptor

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>dist</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<!-- copied from jar-with-dependencies -->
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/dbAccess.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

which is mostly copied from the [Maven Descriptor Refs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html). However my assembled jar still contains the dbAccess.* files. I tried various configurations for exclude.

- changed directory: ..build.directory}/classes
- changed exclude pattern: dbAccess.*, **/*.properties, **/*

The debug output is just:

```
[DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'

[DEBUG] NOT reformatting any files in /media/truecrypt1/Development/workspace_java/baseanalysis/target/classes

[DEBUG] Adding file-set from directory: '/media/truecrypt1/Development/workspace_java/baseanalysis/target/classes'
assembly output directory is: ''

[DEBUG] Adding file-set in: /media/truecrypt1/Development/workspace_java/baseanalysis/target/classes to archive location:
```

The normal resouces filtering works if I put it inside the build section in the pom.

Comment: Whats the exact content of the created jar? Since you don't post your `pom.xml` it's hard to tell whats expected in it. Running plain maven with the descriptor in the question will create a jar with a jar file in it if I remember correctly.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The _unpack_ flag should be _true_. 
The content of the jar, should be the classes compiled in _target/classes_ and the unpack _scope:runtime dependencies_ and not containing the _dbAccess.*_ files

Comment: Sorry, wasn't able to try it out. Works smooth. Thank you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to filter the `dependencySet` as well.
Try updating your assembly descriptor as

```
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    <unpack>true</unpack>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <unpackOptions>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/dbAccess.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </unpackOptions>
</dependencySet>
```