# Maven assembly: Excluded files are not being removed while copying

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to copy my "C" folder into "D" folder excluding pqr.xml file in "C" folder using maven assembly plugin. I tried it with following code but excluded file is there even I have excluded them explicitly. What is the fix for this issue ?

```
  <fileSet>
        <directory>../A/B/C</directory>
        <outputDirectory>X/Y/D</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>C/pqr.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
```

Comment: How about just `<exclude>pqr.xml</exclude>`? Failing that, can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337930/exclude-files-with-maven-assembly-does-not-work